# Different results when compiling with command prompt and BlueJ

Tags: java, command-line, bluej

I'm just starting Java ... again.
I just made a simple program

```
class first
{
    public static void main()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

This runs perfectly fine in BlueJ but it gives an error during run-time when running from command prompt.

This is the error
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`

It's because I didn't give `String args[]` in the `main` parameter list

Till now, I used to give it subconsciously. I know that the string array contains all the parameter values when running but then why is it running in BlueJ?

(BlueJ is a student-friendly Java editor and compiler)

Comment: Please refrain from adding noise like *"Thanks in advance..."*, and note that Java is a proper name, not an abbreviation or acronym (which would be spelled JAVA).

Comment: Maybe your BlueJ IDE is using another version of Java?

Comment: Oh! I forgot to give the error that was shown. Here it is
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`

Comment: @Marcelo Hernández Rishmawy No. BlueJ allows me to select which version of Java to use (in case a PC has multiple versions). BlueJ itself does not come with a JDK. And I have only 1 version of Java.

Comment: I find "Thanks in advance" to be a courteous end to any query on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is valid and will compile to the same thing whether you compile from BlueJ or from the command line.

However, blueJ will let you run any static method in a class (so you can test your functions) where as the command line `java` command will (only) look for a special `main` method to run. This main method tages a String array with all the command line parameters and your program should look like this even though you don't use these command line parameters:

```
class first
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but don't they work in the same manner in the back end? I thought that when I hit the compile button, it gets converted into a DOS command...

Comment: No, that is not correct. Technically BlueJ compiles the class (just like when using the command line `java` compiler), but then BlueJ loads the class and uses reflection to invoke whatever method you have selected. It will **not** use the command line `java` command for it.

Comment: This might be a lame question but why deviate from actual Java mechanisms?

Comment: It will simply allow you to run any method so you can experiment with it. In Java there is really nothing special about the main method, it just happens to be the one the command line tool will try to invoke.